# Spring class RequestBody and MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring

I have class:

```
class TestClass {
  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  private ObjectId parentId;
  private String name;
  private String describe;
  private String privateData;
  public TestClass(ObjectId parentId, String name, String describe, String privateData) {
    this.parrentId = parrentId;
    this.name = name;
    this.describe = describe;
    this.privateDate = privateData;
  }
  // get/set methods...
}
```

Can I use this class in MongoRepository and @RequestBody? Is it safe? parrentId and privateData is private properties and RequestBody does not have to fill them.

mongorepository:

```
public interface TestClassRepository extends MongoRepository<TestClass, String> {
    public TestClass findById(ObjectId id);
}
```

post method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testclass", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody TestClass testClass) {
  testClass.setParentId(...);
  repo.insert(testClass);
}
```

For example:

```
{"name": "test", "describe": "test", "id": "54d5261a8314fe3c650d5b1d", "parentId": "54d5261a8314fe3c650d5b1d", "privateData": "WrongPrivateData"}
```

How can I do that it was impossible to set properties id, parentId, privateDate?

Or need I create new class for RequestBody? I don't want duplicate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be better and safe to use separate models for DAO and VO layers(view). If your models currently looks the same, it doesn't mean that they will stay the same in future. You can use the Dozer Mapping framework for mappings between your models. It's easy,fast and safe. 
If you need to skip some field from mongotemplate mapping use @Transient annotation.

P.S. You don't need findById method, because mongotemplate already have find method which uses key as param. TestClass should have an empty constructor.